# Find in array of references mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this kind of model:

```
MyCollection
{
  ...
  groups : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }],
  ...
}
```

Now how can I find all documents which have a group with known _id?
I tried

```
MyCollection.find({
                'groups' : {
                  $elemMatch : {
                    '$ref' : 'Group',
                    '$id'  : myid
                  }
                }
             }).exec(cb);
```

but it doesn't work. I am really frustrated with this question.

Sample document:

```
{ _id: 52d7dd87f3f1e72c7c000005,
   groups: [ { _id: 52d02565360c206933000013, name: 'groupname' } ],
   date: Thu Jan 16 2014 10:15:00 GMT+0200 (EET),
   ...
}
```

Another try:

```
> db.groups.find({ "name" : "NINFOS13"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d8fad69c7817b52a000012"), "createdAt" : ISODate("2014-01-  17T09:41:42.365Z"), "name" : "NINFOS13", "__v" : 0 }
> db.subjects.insert({groups : [ { _id : ObjectId("52d8fad69c7817b52a000012"), name : "NINFOS13"}]})
> db.subjects.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d8fb7c1c4493a980630c68"), "groups" : [  {  "_id" : ObjectId("52d8fad69c7817b52a000012"),  "name" : "NINFOS13" } ] }
> db.subjects.find({"groups._id" : ObjectId("52d8fb7c1c4493a980630c68")}).count()
0
```

Sorry, I made a mistake this query works!

Comment: I edited, it was a name of a model, I forgot to change it

Comment: Can you provide a sample document from MyCollection?

Comment: Seems like you should just use:  find({"groups._id":myid})

Comment: db.subjects.find({'groups._id' : '52d02565360c206933000013'}).count()
I tried this command, it showed 0, but this group exists definitely and subject entry too

Comment: try:  db.subjects.find({"groups._id" : ObjectId("52d02565360c206933000013")}).count()

Comment: I tried this one as well, the same result

Comment: how do you know there's data there? btw, how did you enter in sample document? Did you paste it in? it's not legal syntax - the id format has to be either a string or ObjectId() or number - what you list isn't legal syntax.

Comment: I used a mongo shell for searching a document, but used other parameters for query. Variable myid is a string containing an id of a group. All data is copy-pasted from terminal

Comment: Could you run this query db.subjects.find().limit(3); from mongo shell and paste results? This does not look like mongo shell output. It will make it easier to see exact types and names.

Comment: The query like `{"group._id": new ObjectId("...")}` works for me. What is the version of your mongo shell? Mine is 2.4.3

Comment: This query doesn't work either. My version is 2.4.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me (using mongo shell):

```
> db.stack.insert({groups: [ { _id: ObjectId("52d02565360c206933000013"), name: "groupname" } ]});    

> db.stack.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d8924b5c90ea648f2a4664"), "groups" : [  {  "_id" : ObjectId("52d02565360c206933000013"),  "name" : "groupname" } ] }

> db.stack.find({"groups._id": ObjectId("52d02565360c206933000013")});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d8924b5c90ea648f2a4664"), "groups" : [  {  "_id" : ObjectId("52d02565360c206933000013"),  "name" : "groupname" } ] }
```

Perhaps you have a typo.